# How can i search file name in specific Github repository

Tags: github, github-api

With [Github's search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/), i can search for repository's name or user's name.

How can i search the file name in the specific Github repository?

I mean how can i do that: in repo jquery/jquery, i search for "selector" keyword, i will have selector.js, selector-sizzle.js, selector-native.js and selector-folder

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

2014: One workaround would be to do a [code search](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code), with:

- `q`: a word than you *know* is in the file you are looking for
- `filename`: the name of the file you are looking for (see "[Search by filename](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code#search-by-filename)")

For instance, if you are looking for `classes.js` in the repo `jquery/jquery`, which you know has to contain the word '`addClass`':

https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+repo:jquery/jquery+filename:classes.js

Take the result with a score > 1

```
"name": "classes.js",
"path": "src/attributes/classes.js",
```

---

[braitsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228315/braitsch) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564760/how-can-i-search-file-name-in-specific-github-repository/25566768?noredirect=1#comment54119158_25566768):

> Instead of "`score`", inspect the "`total_count`" property of the object returned by the query as "`score`" will be absent if the requested file is not found.

---

2022: [Mikhail Vlasenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10919379/mikhail-vlasenko) points to the current "[Searching code](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search=)", adding:

> On the current version, no workaround is necessary, as the search term can be empty when searching with filename.
>
> > Except with [`filename`](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#search-by-filename) searches, you must always include at least one search term when searching source code. For example, searching for [`language:javascript`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%3Ajavascript&type=Code&ref=searchresults) is not valid, while [`amazing language:javascript`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=amazing%20language%3Ajavascript&type=Code&ref=searchresults) is.

Comment: I mean how can i do that: in repo jquery/jquery, i search for "selector" keyword, i will have: selector.js, selector-sizzle.js, selector-native.js and selector-folder

Comment: @ZuzooVn the issue is: I have only seen `filename` criteria in a *code* search. Ie: you cannot (as far as I know) list files, you can only search in files, hence my workaround. In your case, replace `filename:classes.js` with `filename:selector*`

Comment: Instead of "score" inspect the "total_count" property of the object returned by the query as "score" will be absent if the requested file is not found.

Comment: @braitsch Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: on the current version, no workaround is necessary, as the search term can be empty when searching with filename [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#:~:text=Except%20with%20filename%20searches%2C%20you%20must%20always%20include%20at%20least%20one%20search%20term%20when%20searching%20source%20code.)

Comment: @MikhailVlasenko Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get file index's from a repo you can do it the way the file search feature on the web-UI does.

You will however need to replace `1c522832...` with a commit hash.
Also Github's REST API is weird so you will need `-H 'accept: application/json'`

`curl 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree-list/1c52283265a462a100ae63ddf58b4e5884acde86' -H 'accept: application/json' --compressed`

Response:

`{"paths":[".gitignore",....]}`