How to search a file in git repository using filename with GITHUB API
I am looking for a way to search for File with the file name only.
I don't have the file path, like in Github , we have the option to Go to File , in a similar way i want to Search for a file with file name uisng GithubAPI.
I will only have the file name and I want the file path.
I tried with - https://api.github.com/search/code?q=filename:example.txt+repo:test/test-repo
But every time it's giving
{
"total_count": 0,
"incomplete_results": false,
"items": []
}
Although the file is present in src/main/java/notes/example.txt
So, what will be the correct way to get the file path with the file name.

So it's not "GIT API", but "Github API", I'd suggest correcting the title and body of the question.

@RomainValeri I have updated it, do you have any solution for the same

Sorry for the question but it has to start here: did you check github's API documentation about query syntax? I have to guess there's a way to use wildcards.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566768/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/53720557/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+search+file
